# Copy Specific files in a blob from a storage account to a different storage account

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have a list of files in a blob in a storage account that I need to move to another storage account. Is there a way to specifically select blob files and move only the selected subset to a different storage account? If so, how can I do it?

edit: The list of blobs that need to be moved will be updated and the function process will need to run in an ongoing basis

Comment: Do you mean in an ongoing basis or one time?

Comment: Ongoing basis. The list will constantly change and the process will need to be repeated @DrewMarsh

Comment: What generates the list? There are a lot of ways to do this. I'd probably have whatever generates the list throw the filenames into a queue and use a queue-triggered Function do the file move.

Comment: The list is generated by a stored procedure which I am calling from C#. However I was just using the list structure as an intermediary. A queue triggered function does sound easier

Comment: Ok, so you originally asked about moving the blobs and I can answer that, but it seems like you might be in need of a broader architectural solution for the whole problem... end-to-end? When you say "generated by a stored procedure", do you mean you need to invoke this stored procedure every so often to get the list of blobs that need to be moved? Is this stored procedure in an Azure SQL database or is it on-prem? If on-prem, would you have access to the on-prem instance via a VNET? If not, you're looking at some kind of hybrid solution.

Comment: @DrewMarsh it’s an Azure SQL stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most rudimentary approach that I would recommend if you want to use Azure Functions for this is based on the fact that this problem is really about I/O more than it is about compute. So while there are patterns you can use to scale out work with Azure functions, those probably don't make much sense for this kind of problem.

The simplest approach here is to use a single [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) based function. You'll schedule this function to run as frequently as you need. Its job will be to execute your sproc, enumerate the results and then queue up each result for copying via a [`TransferManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.datamovement.transfermanager?view=azure-dotnet) from the Azure Blob Storage SDK.

If you're not familiar with the `TransferManager` class already, it takes care of tracking and optimizing the concurrent throughput of I/O operations for you. You would likely want to create a single [`TransferContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.datamovement.transfercontext?view=azure-dotnet) representing the batch of work the function is working on so you can keep track of progress, deal with failures, handle overwrite situation etc. You would be utilizing the `CopyAsync` method and, again if you're not familiar with this API, there is a parameter on this method named `isServiceCopy`. Since you're copying between two Azure Storage Service accounts you *definitely* want to utilize this so that it is a pure server<->server copy and the I/O doesn't have to pass through the server that your function instance is running on at all; your function ends up being little more than an orchestrator of the copying.

Now, like I said, this is the most rudimentary approach I would suggest. There are other things to consider such as remaining idempotent in the face of any failures. For example, if the stored procedure you're calling only returns a particular blob URI once (e.g. a poor man's queue in SQL server) and your Azure Function fails for some reason, then you would lose that work. I would really need to understand more details about that to prescribe a more durable alternative to that, but you'd definitely want to change this approach so you decouple the actual copying from the execution of the stored procedure to reduce the likelihood of failure there.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement this in C#, now I'm going to move it to a timmer triggered azure-function

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with a Recurrence Logic App:

1. Runs every X time
2. Invoke your Stored Procedure to get the list of the files
3. For each file, use the Copy Blob component to move the source blob to the destination blob